# Invalid URI being generated by transcribe

Tags: url, transcribe

We have a static page created in which we have a bunch of links. The editor is appending the site uri automatically so it generates the wrong link.

For example: We type

```
<a href="{exp:transcribe:uri path='/'}">...</a>
```

then save it. It changes it to

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com/{exp:transcribe:uri path='/'}">...</a>
```

The above of course generates the wrong url:

```
http://www.xyz.com/http://www.xyz.com/pt-br/
```

I am almost certain that it is a config issue but I have no idea what it is. I have searched and have found nothing.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of field is the textarea you're typing this into?

Comment: They are using the link button in the content editor. When I g and click on the html button to change it there, it still add the site uri after we save it.

Comment: What kind of field is the content editor though? Rich Text? MarkItUp? Wygwam? Editor?

Answer (score 0):

hope this still helps.

Use the uri tag either like this

`<a href="{exp:transcribe:uri path='example'}">Example</a>`

or

`<a href="http://domain.tld/{transcribe:language_abbreviation}/{exp:transcribe:uri path='example' site_url='no'}">Example</a>`

You'll need to check that the slashes are correct but the general idea is there.